# swift, UIUserNotificationAction from view controller instead of app delegate

Tags: ios, swift

i´m trying to define an User Notification Action from a ViewController. From my understanding the Notification with Actions has to be set up in the App Delegate.

So here´s my App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {




enum Actions:String{
    case confirmunlock = "CONFIRMUNLOCK_ACTION"
}

var categoryID:String {
    get{
        return "CONFRIMUNLOCK_CATEGORY"
    }
}


// Register notification settings
func registerNotification() {

    // 1. Create the actions **************************************************

    // confirmunlock Action
    let confirmunlockAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    confirmunlockAction.identifier = Actions.confirmunlock.rawValue
    confirmunlockAction.title = "Öffnen"
    confirmunlockAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    confirmunlockAction.authenticationRequired = false
    confirmunlockAction.destructive = false




    // 2. Create the category ***********************************************

    // Category
    let confirmunlockCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    confirmunlockCategory.identifier = categoryID

    // A. Set actions for the default context
    confirmunlockCategory.setActions([confirmunlockAction],
                               forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

    // B. Set actions for the minimal context
    confirmunlockCategory.setActions([confirmunlockAction],
                               forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)


    // 3. Notification Registration *****************************************

    let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: NSSet(object: confirmunlockCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}


// MARK: Application Delegate


func application(application: UIApplication,
                 handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?,
                                            forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification,
                                                                 completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    // Handle notification action *****************************************
    if notification.category == categoryID {

        let action:Actions = Actions(rawValue: identifier!)!

        switch action{

        case Actions.confirmunlock:
            print("Well done!")

        }
    }

    completionHandler()
}



var window: UIWindow?




func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    registerNotification()

    return true
}
```

This works well. When I add "notification.category = categoryID" to one of my LocalNotifications it Logs "Well done". Now the action i would like to call should actually be called from the view controller. It has a lot of variables and you have to be logged in first to access a server to call the action etc. How can I do that? When I put this func in my view controller the action is not getting called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?,
                                            forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification,
                                                                 completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    // Handle notification action *****************************************
    if notification.category == categoryID {

        let action:Actions = Actions(rawValue: identifier!)!

        switch action{

        case Actions.confirmunlock:
            print("Well done!")

        }
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Many Thanks!
Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with NSNotification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName
```

in the Appdelegate where the trigger is. And

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver
```

in the viewdidload of my view controller.

Best
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

This function is part of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol which is implemented by your AppDelegate which is an instance of kind `UIApplication`. You could call your controller from within this function if you have a reference.

Comment: Hi, I did try that. Unfortunately my view controller function does not work from the app delegate. I already start´s with that the selected row is not transferred. So this works in my ViewController (selectedlock is a picker view row):  `let key = keys[selectedlock]` In the App Delegate this gives me always 0 as the selected lock no matter which I have selected in the picker view: `print(ViewController().selectedlock)`

Comment: I guess your application architecture is not ready to be used like that and it seems you need to figure out how class instances and their functions can interact with each other. E.g. you should not rely on global variables (`selectedLock` in `ViewController`) to interact between objects.
One way could be to use notifications: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: Could I use NSNotificationCenter to trigger this action in my ViewController?

Comment: Yes, you need to register an observer in your view controller and post the notification in the app's delegate.